# p-dropdown width issues after upgrading to primeng 9

Tags: angular, primeng

I have recently migrated my project from primeng 7 to primeng 9. I am using p-dropdown and am facing issues with the width of the dropdown. The width was proper in primeng 7. You can see the issue in the attached screenshots.

Primeng 7

[image]

Primeng 9

[image]

I'm not using any css since it worked as expected with the default styling.
I tried using `width : 100%` but the issue still remains. Please help, thanks in advance.

Here is my template:

```
<p-dropdown pTooltip="Select Option" [options]="list"  optionLabel="label"></p-dropdown>
```